# Storing array in session

Tags: arrays, session

I’m trying to handle the contents of an array in WordPress, before I store the array within a session the array outputs as follows;

```
Array
(
    [0] => yes
    [1] => no
)
```

However after storing in $wp_session[‘test_array’] it outputs like;

```
Recursive_ArrayAccess Object
(
[container:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => yes
        [1] => no
    )

[dirty:protected] => 1
)
```

Is there any advise on returning the array to it’s original format so I can handle it easily.

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by serialize() the array before you store it and unserialize() it when you retrieve it.

**For Example:**

```
$wp_session['test_array'] = serialize( array( 'yes', 'no' ) );
$test_array = unserialize( $wp_session['test_array'] );
print_r( $test_array );
```